# Use variable in expression:

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, flow, formula, power-platform

I would like to add a dynamic variable in `addDays` function named Czasookres his value  is equal 14 days.

[image]

How can I insert this variable and is that possible ?

Examples:

```
addDays(utcNow(),Czasookres) - doesn't work
addDays(utcNow(),14) - working well
```

Comment: Hi @Cutmaster, did you try my solution given below? Is it working for you?

Answer (score 0):

You need to surround your variable with
`variables(' ')`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the variable reference using **Dynamic content** section.

**Follow steps**:

1. Go to flow action > open Dynamic content pane
2. Go to **Expression** tab
3. add this formula: `addDays(utcNow(),)` and move cursor after the comma (`,`)

   [image]
4. Click on **Dynamic content** option again and you will be able to select previous action outputs from there, like:

   [image]
5. Select variable you want to add from dynamic content section and Click OK.

Expression should look like:

```
addDays(utcNow(),triggerOutputs()?['body/NumberCol'])
```

Where, `NumberCol` is the [internal name of your SharePoint list column](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/).

`triggerOutputs()?['body/NumberCol']` - this part in expression will change as per your action name & action response structure.

**For example**: If you are using a Power automate flow variable, it will change to:

```
addDays(utcNow(),variables('Czasookres'))
```

Comment: I agree with Ganesh Sanap and feel free to let me know if you have any questions.